# How to a fix LinkageError in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

```
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
java.lang.LinkageError: org/eclipse/ui/forms/IManagedForm
```

I got this error. How to fix this?

Comment: That's rather strange, I've not yet seen a `LinkageError` itself being thrown, usually I only see one of its subclasses (`NoClassDefFoundError` is probably the most common one).

Comment: When do you see this error - can you give us a bit more context around how it happens?  Are you developing an RCP app that uses the org.eclipse.ui.forms plugin?  On your Run Configuration, can you Validate the Plug-ins OK?

Comment: Do you have the class, for some strange reason, twice in your class path?